Prove that $(f+g)(x)<t$ ($t\in\mathbb{R}$) holds if and only if there is a rational number $r$ such that $f(x)<r$ and $g(x)<t-r$.
I got stuck on this question:

Prove that $(f+g)(x)<t$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$, holds if and only if there is a rational number $r$ such that $f(x)<r$ and $g(x)<t-r$.

I think one direction is trivial: If there is a rational number $r$ such that $f(x)<r$ and $g(x)<t-r$, then $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) < r + (t-r) = t$. However, I am baffled by the other direction. I tried to use proof by contradiction:

Suppose that $(f+g)(x) < t$ holds. Assume to the contrary that for all rational number $r$ we have either

$f(x)\geq r$ and $g(x)<t-r$,
$f(x)< r$ and $g(x)\geq t-r$, or
$f(x)\geq r$ and $g(x)\geq t-r$.


Apparently, the third scenrio would reach a contradiction. However, I couldn't figure out how the other two cases would lead to a contradiction. I noticed that I haven't used the condition that $r$ is rational, but I can't see how this condition would kick in.
Moreover, as a follow-up question, how does that statement imply that
\begin{align*}
\{x\in A:(f+g)(x)<t\} = \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\left(\{x\in A:f(x)<r\}\bigcap\{x\in A:g(x)<t-r\}\right),
\end{align*}
where $A$ is the domain of $f$ and $g$?
Could someone please help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!

Reference: Measure Theory by Donald Cohn Proposition 2.1.6.

$f(x)+g(x)<t$ implies that $f(x)<t/2$ and $g(x)<t/2=t-t/2$. Consider a rational $r>t/2$ such that $g(x)<t-r<t-t/2$.

Is $x$ fixed? Or is $ x \in \mathbb{R}$? In the latter case, the statement isn't true. EG Take $f(x) = x, g(x) = - x$. Then clearly $ (f+g)(x) < 1$, but there is no such $r$ for $f(x) < r$.

If $(f+g)(x)<t$, then $f(x)<t-g(x)$. Since the rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there is $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x)<r<t-g(x)$.

@IvánGM Your conclusion is true for a single value, but not for a function (which is the point of my comment).

@CalvinLin I think in the context I am reading, it should be that $x$ is fixed. Because, it then claimed that ${x\in A:(f+g)(x)<t} = \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\left({x\in A:f(x)<r}\bigcap{x\in A:g(x)<t-r}\right)$, where $A$ is the domain of $f$ and $g$.

Your question also has answers here, although I don't know if that's what you're looking for.

@IvánGM Thank you very much! Yes, that's what I'm looking for.
